# Attaching a file to a 'Case' object via REST API

Tags: rest, attachment, .net, force.com-toolkit-for-net

to start with I have defined this class in C#

```cs
public class ContentVersion
{
    public ContentVersion(string filePath)
    {
        Title = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
        VersionData = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
        PathOnClient = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
        ContentLocation = "S";
        Origin = "C";
    }

    public string Title { get; set; }
    public byte[] VersionData { get; set; }
    string PathOnClient { get; set; }
    string ContentLocation { get; set; }
    string Origin { get; set; }
    string Id { get; set; }
}
```

and trying to execute this code:

```cs
ContentVersion contentVersion = new ContentVersion()
{
    Title = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
    VersionData = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
    PathOnClient = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
    ContentLocation = "S";
    Origin = "C";
}
string contentVersionId = connection.ForceClient.CreateAsync("ContentVersion", contentVersion).Result.Id;
```

I keep getting this error

> One of these fields must be set: PathOnClient, ContentUrl.

I have verified to value of `PathOnClient` and it is valid, just before calling `CreatAsync()`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you able to verify the actual request being sent to Salesforce (i.e. Raw XML / JSON being sent)? You may want to use something like requestbin.com and point the request to there to verify contents

Comment: Also I dont think `File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);` will return a Base64 string needed for VersionData